# Setting up a dedicated server on my PC

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I'm trying to set up a dedicated server of CS: GO on my machine because they've gone and taken away the listen server capabilities it seems. The fools! Alls I want to do is practice some stuff, nades and what not.

Anyway, I have the following command:

`srcds -game csgo -ip x.x.x.x -port 27015 -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_allclassic +map de_inferno`

I've done done any changes to the server, just a fresh install from SteamCMD and into that command.

I get:

```
CreateBoundSocket: ::bind returned error [no name available](10049)
Could not establish connection to Steam server.
```

Extra info:

I'm running Windows 7 64bit, have added the server to the firewall rules and also forwarded port 29015 on my router to this machine. It's been a while since I've done this so perhaps I've done it wrong:

```
Protocol    Port Range    Translate To    Trigger Protocol     Trigger Port
Any         27105         27015           -                    -
```

Odly my machine didn't appear on the list of devices so I just entered the IP address. I have a BT home hub (not 100% which version. A black curvy one).

edit: spotted a slight mistake where I had the port as 29015, port rage as the same and translate to as 27015. Corrected this and it's no different.

***Update***

I tried `+port` and `+ip` instead and got different error output:

```
NET_GetBindAddresses found 192.168.12.201: 'Killer e2200 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)'
WARNING: NET_OpenSocket: bind: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL
Trying to open socket on 192.158.1.201
(Repeat a few time)
Socket bind failed (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL)
Network: IP x.x.x.x mode MP, dedicated No, ports 27015 sv / 27005 CL
```

***LAN issue***

I thought I'd at least try and getting it locally before I expose it to the public.
It appears in my LAN tab and I can attempt to connect, but instead I get this in the client console:

`Server requires lobby reservation but is unreserved.`

Please note this is an utterly fresh install and I have done nothing but try and fire it up. No config files or whatever.

***Ports***

I'm not sure my router is doing its job here as http://www.canyouseeme.org/ reports a failure.

Comment: What are you entering for `-ip x.x.x.x`?  Does it begin with `192.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*` *(It should not)*?  Also, I assume "BT Home Hub" is actually a router?  Hubs have no port forwarding (they don't do NAT translation).  Also according to [this thread](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=1993711) it should be `+ip` and `+port`, not `-ip`/`-port`

Comment: The ip is my public IP address. Yes it's a router. I'll try that although I feel there's a bigger issue here as I can't even connect when hosted on LAN.

Comment: Re *"I'm not sure my router is doing its job"* - if it's correctly stealthing ports, you should see "connection timed out" on that site for random ports, and "connection refused" for ports like `27015` which you have forwarded.  [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) is probably a better resource for this.

Comment: Okay, I think this isn't an issue as I learnt to _not_ specify the `+ip`. If I launch the server then do the port checker, it says it's open. The issue now is the `Server requires lobby reservation but is unreserved.` I get this when I connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your server config:

```
sv_allow_lobby_connect_only 0
sv_dc_friends_reqd 0
```